# how can I update my table raw in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I need update My Permission table raw via edit.blade.php file

```
 edit.blade.php
    @extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')


    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
     <h1 class="page-header"> Edit Project</h1>
    @if($permission)
     @include('layouts.partials.alerts')
 <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('status') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="status" class="control-label">Choose Status</label>
                <select name="status" id="status">
                  <option value="{!! $permission->status !!}">{!! $permission->status !!}</option>
                {{ getStatus($permission->status) }}
                </select>
                </div>
                </form>
                </div>
@endif
 </div>


@stop
```

my controller method is this

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $permission = Permission::find($id);
        return view('collaborators.edit')->withPermission($permission);
    }
```

but when I click edit button to edit.blade.php it is only display

```
Edit Project
```

unable to see mu drop down choose status my Permission model is

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Permission extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'permissions';


    protected $fillable = ['status','project_id','collaborator_id'];

    public function scopeProject($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }



      public function project_collaborator()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Collaboration','collaborator_id');
    }

    //
}
```

How can I fix this prob?

Comment: where is your table??

Comment: what did you mean "where is your table??"

Comment: you mentioned "update my table raw"

Comment: my table is "permission"

Answer (score -1):

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="">
```

Here you must set action="" maybe to this {{/edit}} it depends on your route

Comment: yes but action need to form this edit.blade.php view. first I have problem with not display dropdown menu I need to update?

Comment: try to delete `@if($permission)` to find why it doesn't show and change this `<option value="{!! $permission->status !!}">{!! $permission->status !!}</option>` to this `<option value="{{$permission->status}}">{{$permission->status}}</option>`

Comment: when I delete @if($permission) occured following error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: so it shows that you have nothing in $permission, is in your database permission with given id?

Comment: what can I do get $permission?

Comment: What do u mean by what can I do get $permission? ?

Comment: I mean what is the way to get solution this?

Comment: can you check in database if there exists row with given id?